# Debugging AWS-hosted Coturn Server - TURN working, STUN seems not to be

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

Lots of setup information needed, questions coming at the end.
I am hosting a coturn server on an AWS ubuntu instance. I have configured it as follows in turnserver.conf

```
listening-port=3478
external-ip=(external ip)/(internal ip)
relay-ip=(internal ip)
tls-listening-port=5349
verbose
realm=(realm name)
min-port=10000
max-port=20000
lt-cred-mech
user=(username):(password)
```

AWS Security Groups:
Ports 3478 and 5349 open to TCP and UDP traffic from all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses

I am testing this setup using [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

**Results**

1. Server address = "turn:(public ip):3478/?transport=tcp" with username + credential. This seems to be working from what I can tell.

*Client Side*

```
Time    Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port    Priority    URL (if present)    relayProtocol (if present)
0.012   host    1419492315  udp e97c311c-26d9-4083-bfd9-bf004d561c76.local  65276   126 | 30 | 255      
0.124   relay   2654650372  udp (external ip)   16106   1 | 31 | 255    turn:(external ip):3478?transport=tcp   tcp
0.137   Done
```

*Server Side*

```
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: new, realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, lifetime=600
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: realm <(realm name)> user <(username)>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, lifetime=0
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: realm <(realm name)> user <(username)>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private  ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: TCP socket closed remotely (client ip):43114
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: usage: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, rp=3, rb=228, sp=3, sb=288
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: peer usage: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <(username)> realm <(realm name)> origin <>, local (internal ip):3478, remote (client ip):43114, reason: TCP connection closed by client (callback)
Jan 30 13:32:55 ip-(private  ip) turnserver: 28: : session 000000000000000001: delete: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>
```

2. Server address = "turn:(public ip):3478" with username + credential. I can't tell if this is working or not, a few things seem off.

*Client Side*

```
Time    Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port    Priority    URL (if present)    relayProtocol (if present)
0.008   host    3474466919  udp e97c311c-26d9-4083-bfd9-bf004d561c76.local  53711   126 | 30 | 255      
0.020   srflx   710326477   udp (client ip) 34426   100 | 30 | 255  stun:(external ip):3478 
0.100   relay   2859376398  udp (external ip)   14926   2 | 31 | 255    turn:(external ip):3478?transport=udp   udp
0.136   Done
```

**The server stun:(external ip):3478 returned an error with code=701:
STUN server address is incompatible.**
*Server Side*

```
Jan 30 13:45:30 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 783: : session 000000000000000002: new, realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, lifetime=600
Jan 30 13:45:30 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 783: : session 000000000000000002: realm <(realm name)> user <(username)>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
Jan 30 13:45:30 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 783: : session 000000000000000002: refreshed, realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, lifetime=0
Jan 30 13:45:30 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 783: : session 000000000000000002: realm <(realm name)> user <(username)>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
Jan 30 13:45:31 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 784: : session 000000000000000002: usage: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, rp=4, rb=248, sp=4, sb=384
Jan 30 13:45:31 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 784: : session 000000000000000002: peer usage: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>, rp=0, rb=0, sp=0, sb=0
Jan 30 13:45:31 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 784: : session 000000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <(username)> realm <(realm name)> origin <>, local (private ip):3478, remote (client ip):34426, reason: allocation timeout
Jan 30 13:45:31 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 784: : session 000000000000000002: delete: realm=<(realm name)>, username=<(username)>
```

3. Server address = "stun:(external ip):3478

*Client Side*

```
Time    Type    Foundation  Protocol    Address Port    Priority    URL (if present)    relayProtocol (if present)
0.004   host    1256359617  udp e97c311c-26d9-4083-bfd9-bf004d561c76.local  62013   126 | 30 | 255      
0.021   srflx   2080670375  udp (client ip) 38039   100 | 30 | 255  stun:(external ip):3478 
0.127   Done
```

**The server stun:(external ip):3478 returned an error with code=701:
STUN server address is incompatible.**

*Server Side*

```
Jan 30 13:56:08 ip-(private ip) turnserver: 1421: : session 001000000000000001: realm <(realm name)> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
```

**Questions**

1. Why is the behavior different when I add the parameter transport=tcp to the stun address? It seems like leaving it off not only causes the client to attempt to connect to the STUN server (and generate an error); it also yields a different connection close reason (i.e. TCP connection closed by client vs allocation timeout).
2. Should I be specifying transport=tcp? It sort of seems like the TURN server is actually working fine when I include that.
3. What is up with my STUN setup? From what I can glean, it doesn't seem to be working at all.

I've tried changing various aspects of the turnserver.conf with no success

Answer (score 1):

As the trickle-ice page says:

> If you test a STUN server, it works if you can gather a candidate with type
> "srflx". If you test a TURN server, it works if you can gather a candidate
> with type "relay".

You have those. It further says

> Note: errors from onicecandidateerror above are not neccessarily fatal. For
> example an IPv6 DNS lookup may fail but relay candidates can still be gathered
> via IPv4.

which is what is happening.

Note that you will also need to open the relayed port range for udp.